# How do I send periodic SMS notifications to users after a couple days?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement in an MVC application I'm building which requires an email and SMS reminder to be sent to a user 7 days after an update is made on their account in the database.
I don't know how to initiate an action after elapsed time. 
I've never done anything like this and would appreciate tips on the best way to achieve it.
Thanks.

Comment: What don't you know how to do? Wait 7 days? Or send an email and SMS?

Comment: @bornfromanegg Waiting for time to elapse is what I have issues with. I've edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need something to kick off the process.

If you're running on Windows, you can use the task scheduler to run a command line program when you want to do the work. If you're on Linux, you can use `cron`. Other environments have other options.

You can either do the entire process in the program you use a scheduler to run, or you can have the scheduled program call your MVC backend and do the work there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you would do within the MVC application itself. Apart from anything else, if you are running in IIS your application pool is likely to recycle well before 7 days, which means that you couldn't wait within the application even you wanted to.

I believe this problem is best solved by a separate application which is capable of sending the email and SMS. This could run as a scheduled task, perhaps once a day or more frequently if you require.

What you will need is a way of determining what to send. I would suggest adding a new table to your database where you can record whatever details you wish to include in the email/SMS. You would update this table in the MVC application at the same time as updating the account. Each time your new application runs, it will look in this table for anything it needs to send, and process it accordingly.

You will need to consider what to do if someone updates their account more than once in a 7 day period. Are you going to send a separate email for each update, or a single email detailing all the changes made in the last 7 days?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Someone just recommended Quartz as a scheduler we can use. I'm going to check that out now and post my findings later.

Comment: It looks to me like Quartz is for scheduling jobs _within_ your application, which is probably not the best idea in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If You use azure, You can use Worker Role, or web job.

[WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs)

If not You can use any scheduler app.

for example:

[quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)